# Create an initialize script in EmberJS

Tags: ember.js

Emberjs beginner here.

I have an Emberjs app where I need to execute an `initialize` function after jquery has been loaded.

Where would I put the said `initialize` function and how would I call it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for Ember initializers.

```
Ember.Application.initializer({

    name: 'my-initializer',
    after: 'some-other-initializer',

    initialize: function(container, application) {
        application.deferApplicationReadiness();
        application.register(...);

        very_long_initialization_task_returning_promise().then(function() {
            application.advanceApplicationReadiness();
        });
    }
});
```

You can use initializers to preload something in the store, organize dependency injections, etc. The `after` property provides the ability to set the order for the initializers. `deferApplicationReadiness` and `advanceApplicationReadiness` allow you to tell Ember when the application is ready to go.

For more details see http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Application.html#method_initializer.

If you are using ember-cli, make the hash passed to `Ember.Application.initializer` above the default export from a file named `initializers/my-initializer.js`:

```
export default {
    name: 'my-initializer',
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this...  Assuming timing is not critical between loading everything and the DOM being ready, etc...  Click on "Run code snippet" to see the "JavaScript" heading change after 1 second.

```js
var App = Ember.Application.create();

App.reopen({
  ready: function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        Ember.$('#thing').text('FavaBean');
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/handlebars-1.0.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/ember-latest.js"></script>

<h1 id="thing">JavaScript</h1>
```